# How to put a string value to the openTSDB

Tags: c#, opentsdb

Data specification in below link mentioned that, a numeric value to store at the given timestamp for the time series is an integer or a floating point value.

http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/writing.html

But by using api/put the value might be string,integer or float.

http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/put.html

Getting bad request exception, while putting string values.

How can i put the string value to the open TSDB?

Comment: in PUT doc there's a mention of String type - but in my opinion it means the quoted values i.e. int -> 32, floating point -> 32.2. string -> '32'

Comment: kindly paste the code/curl request , etc you're making which gave you exception